# System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access to the path 'C:\runtime\Secrets\host.json' is denied in Azure Functions Windows container

Tags: dockerfile, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, windows-container

Based on [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker/blob/master/host/2.0/nanoserver-1803/Dockerfile)
I'm running Azure Functions runtime inside a Windows container.

I want to bring my own secrets. So I add my own host.json into the `runtime\secrets` folder and set the storage type to `files`:

**host_secret.json:**

```
{
  "masterKey": {
    "name": "master",
    "value": "***fancy-code-for-host-admin-and-keys-api***",
    "encrypted": false
  },
  "functionKeys": [
    {
      "name": "default",
      "value": "***fancy-code-for-functions***",
      "encrypted": false
    }
  ]
}
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
....
ADD host_secret.json C:\\runtime\\Secrets\\host.json
ENV AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType=files
....
```

When starting the container and the function app, it does not respond and shows

> Function host is not running.

checking the logs I find

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access to the path 'C:\runtime\Secrets\host.json' is denied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The container is running as `ContainerUser` and hence this user needs access to this file.

```
ADD host_secret.json C:\\runtime\\Secrets\\host.json

USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN icacls "c:\runtime\secrets" /t /grant Users:M
USER ContainerUser

ENV AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType=files
```

This grants modify access rights to users inside the container - a group `ContainerUser` is member of.